# How to autofill suggestion after clicking in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

can someone pls help me with this :-

This is what I am getting as a response from the api which is google place api , now I want to make ui on top of it where we will have 4 boxes in first box I will enter the letter and on the basis of that letter place suggestions will come up and when we click on that suggestion other fields such as city , country , state should be autofilled can someone help to create that type of ui ,

```
   {
                "predictions": [
                    {
                        "description": "Telangana Institute of Medical Sciences - TIMS, Gachibowli, Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
                        "matched_substrings": [
                            {
                                "length": 9,
                                "offset": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "place_id": "ChIJ9WF2yiKTyzsRz6Zu1dewbqQ",
                        "reference": "ChIJ9WF2yiKTyzsRz6Zu1dewbqQ",
                        "structured_formatting": {
                            "main_text": "Telangana Institute of Medical Sciences - TIMS",
                            "main_text_matched_substrings": [
                                {
                                    "length": 9,
                                    "offset": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "secondary_text": "Gachibowli, Hyderabad, Telangana, India"
                        },
                        "terms": [
                            {
                                "offset": 0,
                                "value": "Telangana Institute of Medical Sciences - TIMS"
                            },
                            {
                                "offset": 48,
                                "value": "Gachibowli"
                            },
                            {
                                "offset": 60,
                                "value": "Hyderabad"
                            },
                            {
                                "offset": 71,
                                "value": "Telangana"
                            },
                            {
                                "offset": 82,
                                "value": "India"
                            }
                        ],
                        "types": [
                            "hospital",
                            "health",
                            "point_of_interest",
                            "establishment"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Telangana, India",
                        "matched_substrings": [
                            {
                                "length": 9,
                                "offset": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "place_id": "ChIJQ-0plNtQMzoRWUBZQad772M",
                        "reference": "ChIJQ-0plNtQMzoRWUBZQad772M",
                        "structured_formatting": {
                            "main_text": "Telangana",
                            "main_text_matched_substrings": [
                                {
                                    "length": 9,
                                    "offset": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "secondary_text": "India"
                        },
                        "terms": [
                            {
                                "offset": 0,
                                "value": "Telangana"
                            },
                            {
                                "offset": 11,
                                "value": "India"
                            }
                        ],
                        "types": [
                            "administrative_area_level_1",
                            "political",
                            "geocode"
                        ]
                    }
            
            }
```

This is what I have as a code for getting the data from api ..can someone help me further how to proceed

```
 import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import axios from "axios";
import { withSnackbar } from "notistack";

import TextField from "../../../shared/mui/TextField";
import Select from "../../../shared/mui/SelectField";
class Information extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            locations: [],
            loading: false,
        };
    }

      handleSuggestions = (event) => {
                const newValue = event.target.value;
                if (newValue.toString().length < 1) {
                    this.setState({
                        locations: [],
                        loading: false,
                    });
                }
                if (newValue.toString().length >= 1) {
                    console.log("success");
                    this.setState({
                        loading: true,
                    });
                    axios({
                        url:
                            "http://localhost:8080/testdata/telangana",
                        method: "get",
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    }).then(
                        (success) => {
                            console.log(success.data.predictions);
                            this.setState({
                                locations: success.data.predictions,
                                loading: false,
                            });
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.log(error.message);
                            this.setState({
                                loading: false,
                            });
                        }
                    );
                }
            };

    render() {
            console.log(this.state.locations);
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
                    <Grid container spacing={10} className="form-sec">
                        <Grid item xs={12} className="pb-0">
                        
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={6} className="pt-10">
                        
                            <div className="mt-25">
                                <FormControl fullWidth>
                                    <Autocomplete
                                        id="country-select-demo"
                                        style={{ width: 300 }}
                                        options={this.state.locations}
                                        autoHighlight
                                        loading={this.state.loading}
                                        filterOptions={(items) => items} // Just a hack to return all items given as options
                                        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                            this.props.handleSuggestions(
                                                event,
                                                newValue
                                            );
                                        }}
                                        getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                                            return option.main_text;
                                        }}
                                        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
                                            if (option === value) {
                                                this.props.render(option);
                                            }
                                        }}
                                        renderOption={(option) => (
                                            <React.Fragment>
                                                <div>
                                                    {option.description}
                                                    <br />
                                                </div>
                                            </React.Fragment>
                                        )}
                                        renderInput={(params) => (
                                            <TextField
                                                {...params}
                                                name="addressline1"
                                                label="Address Line 1"
                                                error={
                                                    this.props.data
                                                        .addressline1Error
                                                }
                                                value={this.props.data.predictions}
                                                onChange={
                                                    this.props.handleChange &&
                                                    this.handleSuggestions
                                                }
                                            
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </FormControl>
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="mt-25">
                                <FormControl fullWidth>
                                    <TextField
                                        id="postalCode"
                                        label="Postal Code"
                                        name="postalCode"
                                        value={this.props.data.postalCode}
                                        error={this.props.data.postalCodeError}
                                    />
                                </FormControl>
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="mt-25">
                                <FormControl fullWidth>
                                    <TextField
                                        id="state"
                                        label="state"
                                        name="postalCode"
                                        value={this.props.data.state}
                                        error={this.props.data.stateError}
                                    />
                                </FormControl>
                                {}
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={6} className="pt-10">
                            <div className="mt-25">
                                <FormControl fullWidth>
                                    <TextField
                                        id="AddressLine2"
                                        label="Address Line 2"
                                        name="addressline2"
                                        value={this.props.data.addressline2}
                                        error={this.props.data.addressline2Error}
                                    />
                                </FormControl>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mt-25">
                                <FormControl fullWidth>
                                    <TextField
                                        label="City"
                                        name="city"
                                        value={this.props.data.city}
                                        error={this.props.data.cityError}
                                    />
                                </FormControl>
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="mt-25">
                                <Select
                                    id="country"
                                    name="country"
                                    lable="Country"
                                    value={this.props.data.country}
                                    error={this.props.data.countryError}
                                    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                                >
                                    
                                </Select>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <div className="align-center">
                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    size="large"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                >
                                    Set company information
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: in your render method just put a condition to check if locations exist, and therefore render a div with position absolute and higher zindex

Comment: I can only see a component Autocomplete depending on 'locations'. Perhaps look at that component

Comment: @SteveTomlin can u pls guide whats wrong .. assumption is I am getting the suggestions the only thing is when I click on suggestion other places like city state country should be autofilled , I am new to react and m stuck here

Comment: The component Autocomplete is coming from where? That is the component which is determining how it behaves.  Perhaps create a codesandbox example showing your full implementation

Comment: @SteveTomlin , pls check now  , I have added import statements ...

Comment: ok so the problem here is knowing how to use Material UI AutoComplete. Use this sandbox and add to it to find the problem - https://codesandbox.io/s/l7syq

Comment: can u just add one more box and on the selection of suggestion the other field get filled others I will try ..@SteveTomlin

Comment: I haven't created it. Its a boilerplate. You can personally edit it and save your changes to test it.

Comment: @SteveTomlin , then again arrived at same starting point..by the way thanks